# Python Comprehensions - what is the order of projection vs filtering?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have this snippet(generate squares for even numbers in a set)

is the projection done first and then filtered, or is the filter run on each iteration of x in range(100)?

```py
output_list = [x*x for x in range(100) if x % 2  == 0]
print("Output List using for loop:", output_list)
```

Is there a way to find out which order of execution between the projection & filtering?

Comment: first filter. This is equivalent to `for x in range(100): if x%2==0: l.append(x)`

Comment: Well, usually the first place to start is to consult the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Then, you can always disassemble python into it's bytecode to see exactly what is happening: `import dis; print(dis.dis('[x*x for x in range(100) if x % 2  == 0]'))` Note, in Python >= 3.7, `dis.dis` automatically recurses into any code-objects encountered in the dissasmbler, making it much more user-friendly for list-comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

For each element in the iterator (`range(100)`), the filter expression is evaluated first and only if it evaluates to true is the projection expression evaluated.

You can verify this with this code snippet:

```py
[print("A", x)
 for x in range(10)
 if print("B", x) or x % 2 == 0]
```